# Caps lock and Audio Mute LED not working, /sys/class/led Folder Empty

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, 22.04

I am dual booting with Windows and Ubuntu, for some reason on Windows my Caps Lock LED indicator works, and the audio mute LED. But when I enter Ubuntu its not working, the caps lock works but the Light doesn't show up (same with the audio mute). I then realized that `/sys/class/led` is empty. When i enter recovery mode its not, and the LED works. But I cannot add files to it, it just doesn't let me. Can someone please respond and help me with this, its driving me crazy.